# EF4.1 - Try update many rows

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I need to update all rows of my table when user visits one specific page.
All fields need to be updated to "false".
I tried this code:

```
var history = db.UserHistory.Where(m => m.UserID == id);
TryUpdateModel(history);
history.IsActive = false;
db.SaveChanges();
```

But it throws me an error message. 
Anyone could help me with this update?

Comment: And what does TryUpdateModel do?

Comment: DamienG: "Updates the specified model instance using values from the controller's current value provider" Part of .NET 4

Comment: And whats your model look like

Comment: I changed a little my code, I exchanged "var" type for UserHistory, it throws me this exception: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MvcWebRole1.Models.UserHistory>' to 'MvcWebRole1.Models.UserHistory'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get at first that LINQ didn`t update many rows at once, I have to make a loop and update each one. My final code is this one:

```
var history = db.UserHistory.Where(m => m.UserID == id).ToList();
TryUpdateModel(history);
history.ForEach(m => m.IsActive = false);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like you're just selecting a single entry you want to probably want to append .FirstOrDefault() to your first line, which should appear with intellisense.

```
var history = db.UserHistory.Where(m => m.UserID == id).FirstOrDefault();
TryUpdateModel(history);
history.IsActive = false;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Right now you're returning an IQueryable as opposed to a single entry. FirstOrDefault will return a single UserHistory entity, so at least you'd be passing a single item to TryUpdateModel.

Comment: Actualy my question is about many results to update. I will have for sure more than one line, so I would like to update all.

Comment: I see maybe I have to use foreach to update each row? The value to update is always the same, is always false, and the colunm is always the same too...